# Oracle APEX: Marquee a text that is stored in an oracle db table

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm developing an application in Oracle Application Express, I'm told to create a marquee with the text stored in a table in Oracle DB.
Is it possible to achieve using Javascript?

Comment: There's lots of questions on SO about rendering Marquee using JavaScript.  Have you looked at any of them?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+marquee

Comment: Also see this thread in the OTN forums: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=304388

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Create a hidden item to look up the marquee text from an Oracle table. Then create a marquee like those suggested above. Instead of hardcoding the marquee content in Javascript, use the hidden variable like so: `&P1_HIDDEN_ITEM.`